# what is wrong with this method of animating a jpg background that dynamically changes with buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, background, flash-cs5

OK here what I'm envisioning and keep in mind ive only just started playing with flash so I really am a total novice at this point:

I want to have two buttons which load different jpegs which are pretty large (about 5000 width x 600 height) to animate as the page background.  so in my BG layer for the main timeline i added a container movie clip (5000x600 also) and in the container movie clip's timeline i have it classic tweening across the stage back and forth.  then on the main timeline i have my two buttons which are supposed to load the backgrounds.  the thing that seems to be messing it all up is the fact that i call "stop();" in my action script to stop on my 3rd frame of the main timeline after the preloader etc.  in my testing i added yet another movie clip that animates and it keeps animating when i cal stop(); but the background image is not animating any more.

sorry for my lack of understand and THANK YOU for your patience ;)

anyways here is the main action script code:

```
import fl.transitions.*;

import fl.transitions.easing.*;

// tween the main menu into place upon opening

//var moveTween:Tween = new Tween(mainmenu_mc, "y", Elastic.easeOut, mainmenu_mc.y, 70, 2, true);

// claim MCs from library to use on stage when needed using addChild

var bg1:blueBG = new blueBG();

var bg2:greenBG = new greenBG();

var bg3:testBG = new testBG();
//var p4:page4 = new page4;


containerBG_mc.addChild(bg3);

var pageMoveTween:Tween = new Tween(containerBG_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);



blueBtn_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn1Click);

crazyBtn_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn2Click);




function btn1Click (event:MouseEvent):void {


var btn1Outro:Tween = new Tween(containerBG_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);

btn1Outro.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, runBtn1Transition);

function runBtn1Transition (event:TweenEvent):void {

containerBG_mc.removeChildAt(1);

containerBG_mc.addChild(bg1);

var btn1Intro:Tween = new Tween(containerBG_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);

}

}




function btn2Click (event:MouseEvent):void {


var btn2Outro:Tween = new Tween(containerBG_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 1, true);

btn2Outro.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, runBtn2Transition);

function runBtn2Transition (event:TweenEvent):void {

containerBG_mc.removeChildAt(1);

containerBG_mc.addChild(bg2);

var btn2Intro:Tween = new Tween(containerBG_mc, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);

}

}
```

and of course there is a stop(); action on the 3rd frame of the main timeline in a different action script layer

SUMMARY:

3 layers:
AS3 layer
button layer
BG layer

duties:
AS3 layer just has a stop action on frame 3
button layer contains two buttons to dynamically change the background jpeg image. the action script for this layer is what i posted above
BG layer has the containerBG_mc movie clip instance which on its own timeline animates left and right

if you need further clarification let me know

Comment: it's not perfectly clear what you want and the code is... too much. can you please summarize?

Comment: anyhow a BIG background may slow things down. I would otherwise dynamically load background "slices" that you attach as the the program runs. when they finish you will restart from the first (if you designed them like the last joins well with the first one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're tweening something with the timeline in the container movieclip, so you're not tweening  the container itself. Than you're adding movieclips to the container, so they are not affected by the tween.

What you want to do is add the backgrounds to the movieclip you're tweening in the container like this:

```
containerBG_mc.tweened_mc.addChild( bg3 );
```

You can set the name to tweened_mc in the properties-panel when selecting that tweened object.

Comment: this site still never ceases to amaze me, absolutely fantastic concise answer - implemented it and it worked perfectly! thanks tim you are amazing! and a note to anyone else doing similar things, when i went into the movie clip timeline for my containerBG_mc and changed teh graphic to its own movie clip (tweened_mc) i had to redo the whole timeline because at the other tweening points it was not considered "tweened_mc." thanks again this is super useful to know, i didn't know the child timeline wasnt editting the movie clip itself - i learned something WOOT!

Comment: Glad to be of help.. Also I want to point out that you're better off using Tweening libraries for this, like Caurina Tweener, Tweensy or TweenLite. There are a lot of tutorials for these.. Less typing and a lot faster.. :)